# Android - Formatting current time

Tags: android, time

By using:

```
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy h:mm");
String currentDate = formatter1.format(calendar1.getTime());
```

I obtain something in this format: `06/10/2016 7:25`
However, what I need is in this format: `06/10/2016 7h25`
. Notice that the delimeter **`:`** became `h`

What change should I make to obtain this required result?

Comment: have you tried unicode? /u0030

Comment: Um, you should change the `:` that's in your format to `'h'` (note the quotes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy h'h'mm");

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html:

> Within date and time pattern strings, unquoted letters from 'A' to
>   'Z' and from 'a' to 'z' are interpreted as pattern letters
>   representing the components of a date or time string. **Text can be
>   quoted using single quotes (') to avoid interpretation.**

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

As `SimpleDateFormat(String)` seems to be not supporting characters escaping - you can construct the string you need from 3 strings:

```
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy h");
SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");
String currentDate = formatter1.format(calendar1.getTime())
    + "h" + formatter2.format(calendar1.getTime());
```